# How to clear the stored Edittext value (stored file) through a button click?

Tags: java, android

Let me explain (My English is bad so, sorry). I've created an activity where there's three Edittext boxes to fill up. After filling all up, there's a "Submit" button which passes the data to another activity to be later displayed in their respective textviews. The problem is, whenever i fill up those edittexts and pass the information, it gathers with the data previously passed before. I have a 'clear' button but that only helps to clear the textview display. I wanna make it to clear the stored data so that the next time, when i pass the data again, the textviews show the newly passed data instead of mixing up with the previous data.

An image example below:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/txv81.png][1]

I wanna make sure that when i key in the editexts next time, the activity should only display what iv'e keyed in during that moment and make the 'clear' button erase all the previuosly stored data.

Here's the FillInOwnStory code (fill in the edittexts in this activity)

```
package com.example.msi.astorydrivengame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class FillInOwnStory extends AppCompatActivity {


Button storysubmit;
Button menubutton2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_in_own_story);

    fillStoryName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillStoryName);
    fillAuthor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillAuthor);
    fillStoryDescp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillStoryDescp);
    storysubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.storysubmit);
    menubutton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menubutton2);
}

private EditText fillStoryName;
private EditText fillAuthor;
private EditText fillStoryDescp;
private TextView StoryNameColumn;
private TextView AuthorColumn;
private TextView DescpColumn;


public void buttonClickFunction26(View view) {
    fillStoryName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillStoryName);
    String StoryNameFilled = fillStoryName.getText().toString();
    fillAuthor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillAuthor);
    String AuthorNameFilled = fillAuthor.getText().toString();
    fillStoryDescp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fillStoryDescp);
    String DescpFilled = fillStoryDescp.getText().toString();

    try{
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("storyname.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        out.write(StoryNameFilled.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }catch(java.io.IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("author.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        out.write(AuthorNameFilled.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }catch(java.io.IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("descp.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        out.write(DescpFilled.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }catch(java.io.IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FillColumn.class);
    intent.putExtra("storyname_label", StoryNameFilled);
    intent.putExtra("author_label", AuthorNameFilled);
    intent.putExtra("descp_label", DescpFilled);
    startActivity(intent);


}
}
```

Here's the FillColumn code (the edittext values are displayed in this textviews given.)

```
package com.example.msi.astorydrivengame;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class FillColumn extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView StoryNameColumn;
TextView AuthorColumn;
TextView DescpColumn;
Button menubutton3;
Button clearbutton;
String xxx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_column);

    StoryNameColumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StoryNameColumn);
    AuthorColumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AuthorColumn);
    DescpColumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DescpColumn);
    menubutton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menubutton3);
    clearbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbutton);


    Intent intentx = getIntent();
    StoryNameColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("storyname_label"));
    try {
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("storyname.txt");

        if (instream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            String line;

            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                StoryNameColumn.setText(line);
            }
        }
        instream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AuthorColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("author_label"));
    try {
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("author.txt");

        if (instream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            String line;

            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                AuthorColumn.setText(line);
            }
        }
        instream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DescpColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("descp_label"));
    try {
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("descp.txt");

        if (instream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            String line;

            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                DescpColumn.setText(line);
            }
        }
        instream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void buttonClickFunction30(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StoryPageChoices.class);
    String strNAME = "Slot 1";
    intent.putExtra("NewStory", strNAME);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void clear(View v) {
    StoryNameColumn.setText("");
    AuthorColumn.setText("");
    DescpColumn.setText("");

}
}
```

I know my coding's not clean and messed up and my English's bad so, sorry for that.

Comment: I am quite not sure though tell me this you are setting the text to Textview from extras and from the file also right. I think it's taking the old text because the old text is there in those files. Clear the old file content and re-write it and try or set text only from extras or from file

Comment: Yes, that's it sir, i didn't knew how to convey it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a text as an empty string in your `EditText`

```
onClick(View view){
    ----
    yourEditText.getText().clear();  
    //or
    yourEditText.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably cause you are doing :

this line sets your text as you want from the previous activity:

```
StoryNameColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("storyname_label"));
```

But right after that line you are using this code that overrides the value you set into the `StoryNameColumn`. Try removing all those lines that read from the file.

```
try {
    InputStream instream = openFileInput("storyname.txt");

    if (instream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
        BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

        String line;

        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            StoryNameColumn.setText(line);
        }
    }
    instream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDITED :**

```
public class FillColumn extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView StoryNameColumn;
TextView AuthorColumn;
TextView DescpColumn;
Button menubutton3;
Button clearbutton;
String xxx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_column);

StoryNameColumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StoryNameColumn);
AuthorColumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AuthorColumn);
DescpColumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DescpColumn);
menubutton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menubutton3);
clearbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbutton);


Intent intentx = getIntent();
StoryNameColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("storyname_label"));
AuthorColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("author_label"));
DescpColumn.setText(intentx.getStringExtra("descp_label"));
}


public void buttonClickFunction30(View view) {

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StoryPageChoices.class);
String strNAME = "Slot 1";
intent.putExtra("NewStory", strNAME);
startActivity(intent);

}

public void clear(View v) {
StoryNameColumn.setText("");
AuthorColumn.setText("");
DescpColumn.setText("");

  }
}
```

Comment: Which lines bro? I'm still a newbie so i don't know what are you talking about,

Comment: I did what you said, but when i go to another activity, the data which i just passed is not there anymore. It's there after i submit it, but the data's not staying there.

Comment: i edited my answer. try to copy this class and see if this works